# How does NSIS set section's size requirement automatically?

Tags: nsis

We have an installer with multiple components that each has their own section. I'm trying to find out how our existing code actually sets the size of each section. We have 3 components that if checked/unchecked will update the "Space required" value on the components page.

The new section that I added currently does not update this value. What I can't seem to find in our existing code is where this actually gets set.

I did some research and found this post below where a user said "the size gets set automatically". But how?
https://nsis-dev.github.io/NSIS-Forums/html/t-291064.html

I looked up the NSIS docs and saw some ways to set this including:

- `AddSize`
- `SectionSetSize`

You can even use `CopyFiles` to set an estimated size of the files which then can be used by the installer.

I searched our NSIS directory for all of the methods above and could not get any results for `AddSize` or `SectionSetSize`. I also didn't see any instances of `CopyFiles` where the developer added the estimated space in kilobytes. Is there some NSIS magic that sets this size automatically that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NSIS automatically sets the size of a section based on the `File` instructions in that section.

`AddSize` can be used if you know you are doing some external operation that also uses disk space. You can use `SectionSetSize` at run-time if you only know the size when you are running on the end-users system after doing some type of calculation.

Comment: Thanks! That helped! We did have File instructions. However, they lived inside a Function which was called by our section in two places. I guess NSIS can't calculate the size of a section if the File instructions are not directly inside the section. I moved the logic outside of the Function and now the size is properly calculated.